# convert bstr into datetime format

Tags: visual-c++, wmi

I am using function of Operating system information and its properties for `InstallDate` of Operating System. i got output in string format with `BSTR` variant type

```
   VARIANT var1;

   hres = pclsObj->Get(L"InstallDated", 0, &var1, 0, 0);
   wcout << "Event Log time generated : " << var1.bstrVal << endl;
```

It gives output in string format..20121110080510. I guess it's date and time only. How should I parse this property or function in date format?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that seems to be the date in string format - YYYYMMDDHHMM.

I think you can use [sscanf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkx076cy.aspx) function to pick year, month, date etc from the string, after which you can store it in the [SYSTEMTIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.

Answer (score 0):

**C++**

Quick excerpt from my own code

Here timeGenerated is a BSTR with value of 20190507140217.848430-000
and eventLogItem.TimeGenerated is a std::string

```
if (timeGenerated.bstrVal != NULL)
{
    // convert to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
    eventLogItem.TimeGenerated = _bstr_t(timeGenerated.bstrVal);
    eventLogItem.TimeGenerated = eventLogItem.TimeGenerated.substr(0, 4) + "-" +
        eventLogItem.TimeGenerated.substr(4, 2) + "-" +
        eventLogItem.TimeGenerated.substr(6, 2) + " " +
        eventLogItem.TimeGenerated.substr(8, 2) + ":" +
        eventLogItem.TimeGenerated.substr(10, 2) + ":" +
        eventLogItem.TimeGenerated.substr(12, 2);
}
```

output **2019-05-07 14:09:32**

Code for time zone

```
// Get the current timezone information
TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION timezone;
memset(&timezone, 0, sizeof(PTIME_ZONE_INFORMATION));
GetTimeZoneInformation(&timezone);
```

Full source code on [my blog](http://malcolmswaine.com/c-convert-a-bstr-date-time-to-a-stdstring-date-time-2-capable-string-with-offset/?fbclid=IwAR3-FXCsY0naRDm-gVJQwWYQhOSottkmsegpn9-wRGmeVp_vBanbBMB5qRU#.XNGqW3Xw2ak.facebook)

Answer (score 0):

If you use *boost::posix_time* to represent date/time information in your application then you can implement the following conversion for event log dates:

```
// Helper function
std::string wstring_to_utf8(const std::wstring& str)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> myconv;
    return myconv.to_bytes(str);
}

VARIANT var1;
hres = pclsObj->Get(L"InstallDated", 0, &var1, 0, 0);
boost::posix_time::time_input_facet *tif = new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet;
tif->format("%Y%m%d%H%M%s-000");
std::istringstream iss(wstring_to_utf8(var1.bstrVal));
iss.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), tif));
boost::posix_time::ptime datetime;
iss >> datetime;
```

Don't be confused if you see *new* operator but don't see *delete* since time_input_facet structure is deleted automatically.